# How to store necessary set of bitmaps in memory while selecting themes in live wallpaper

Tags: android

i am new to android i am working on android live wallpaper.i checked live wallpaper examples
but i dint find how to change set of bitmap images while selecting different themes in settings part of live wallpaper.I have three themes for each theme there are almost 10 images 
i dont know how to change entire set of images for each theme.i am using list preference for selecting different theme please somebody help me by answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store them in a hashmap. Ive never made a wallpaper but I would just set the images as bitmaps from the resources in the class declaration and then put those into hashmaps and set the keys as int's like this

```
Bitmap one = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(R.drawable.one);
int one = 0;
HashMap<int,Bitmap> map = new HashMap<int,Bitmap>();
```

Since I dont know how a wallpaper works Im guessing that it sets up like an activity so in the onCreate() or what have you, you would load the hashmaps like so:

```
map.add(one,one);
```

Comment: Thanks James for answering my question